# Kendo and Design on Tablets

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, tablet

Actually, I'm developing a MVC application with Kendo controls. I'had realice a Web template with kendo controls and show correclty.

For the web, Kendo controls display correctly, so I decided to do it for mobile.
The result was good, it worked DEMO following the example of the Kendo Telerik TabStrip.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3877624/Kendo/mobile_example.gif

Agree, no problem. (I thought) I'll do the same for tablets ...

I copied with the same contents of the view into a **new view for tablets**, and the same content of **the layout for the tablet**. Ultimately, it has been copied and pasted, but identifying one for tablet and one for mobile.

When I run the application on a tablet emulator, open the template and **the content of the tablets correctly**, but is not the same design as seen on mobile and do not know what exactly is going on.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3877624/Kendo/tablet_example-%5B1280x768%5D.jpg

**On the tablet, the background is always black, the colors are not displayed correctly, etc.** I don't know if the probler are from **Opera emulator** or other cause, because the files are the same.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1st screenshot is of Kendo UI Mobile in iOS styling, and the second is in Android styling. For whatever reason, Kendo is detecting iOS in one case and Android in another, and tries to re-style itself to fit the native look of the OS.

You can see the differences here: http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/overview/index.html#/ by choosing different OSes on the top right "OS Simulator Mode"

You can force Kendo UI Mobile to always use the iOS look by adding this when you initialize the application:

```
new kendo.mobile.Application($(document.body), {
    platform: "ios"
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This is real problem. When I change the agent to iPad (for example) this works fine.